# sRGBEncoding in not working in THREE.EffectComposer

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to do post processing in threejs scene
here I'm using EffectComposer for doing it
but im not able to enble sRGBEncoding in renderTarget.

```
const renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(
    sizes.width,
    sizes.height,
    {
        minFilter:THREE.LinearFilter,
        magFilter:THREE.LinearFilter,
        format:THREE.RGBAFormat,
        encoding:THREE.sRGBEncoding

    }
)
```

and my effectComposer is like that

```
const effectComposer = new EffectComposer(renderer,renderTarget);
effectComposer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio,2));
effectComposer.setSize(sizes.width,sizes.height)
```

but sRGBEncoding is not working

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using post processing, use a gamma correction pass at the end of your pass chain. This will ensure a sRGB encoded output:

```
composer.addPass( new ShaderPass( GammaCorrectionShader ) );
```

Full example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_3dlut

Comment: but it will only work if we are using shaderPass only. if you add different pass (other than shaderPass). it wont work